# PDF to Image using PDFBox 1.8.9 text overlapped

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am trying to convert PDF to Image using PDFBox 1.8.9. The fonts are getting overlapped. I know this problem does not occur in PDFBox 2.0 SNAPSHOT. But it cannot be used in production until it is officialy released.

Below is the code:

```
PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("test.pdf"));  
List<PDPage> pages = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
int pageCounter = 1;
for (PDPage page : pages) {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = page.convertToImage();
    File imageFile = new File(String.format("/tmp/pdf-image-%s.jpg", pageCounter));
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", imageFile);     
    pageCounter++;
}
```

The font appears similar to PDF except overlapping?

When I try to convert PDF to Image using pdfbox-app-1.8.9.jar through command line, the Image is generated with a different font. Does PDFBox has any option to specify a custom font using .ttf? In that case, how can I specify?

Actual PDF:

[image]

Converted Image using above code:

[image]

Converted Image using commandline:

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example screen shot?

Comment: I doubt it is a different font if it is the same computer - maybe the image resolution is different?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Does image resolution has any effect on this? because, I already tried it by changing the resolutions.

Comment: @jaghan no, I just meant that it might give the illusion. I'd really like to see the screenshots that Pekka asked for.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have added the screen shot

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have added the screen shot

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks, but what I meant is screenshot showing that rendering from java code and rendering from cmdline app is different. The problem that the fonts are incorrectly rendered is known (I believe we solved over 100 font related issues in 2.0!), and as you wrote, will work in 2.0. This can't be fixed in 1.8.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The screenshot given here is the actual PDF and the converted Image. Here the PDF is converted to Image using the above code.

Comment: @Pekka웃 But you said that "I try to convert PDF to Image using pdfbox-app-1.8.9.jar through command line, the Image is generated with a different font" - from which I understand that the cmdline generated image is different from the java code generated image. That is what I'm interested in because that sounds really weird.

Comment: Why are you all talking to me? I didn't say nothin'

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have added the screen shot of the image converted using pdf-box-app-1.8.9.jar in commandline. Please have a look. Kindly reply to Jaghan instead of Pekka

Comment: @jaghan Thanks for the screenshot, and sorry for the confusion. Next useful thing needed would be the PDF, if you can upload it somewhere.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Here is the link http://www.docdroid.net/12xff/print-to-upload.pdf.html

Comment: @jaghan I tested and the renderings are identical, i.e. no overlapping. Could it be that it ran on different systems, or with different rights?

Comment: In case of your document the fonts are only referenced by name (**Helvetica-Bold**, **Times-Bold**, **Helvetica**, **Helvetica-Oblique**), not embedded. The actual font used depends strongly on environmental resources.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am running it on ubuntu 12.4. Is there a possibility to tell the document to use custom fonts i.e .ttf?

Comment: @mkl There is no way of forcing PDFBOX to load the missing fonts using .ttf instead of relying on the system resource?

Comment: @jajhan I think it is possible, you could try to change the file "FontMapping.properties" and/or the file "PDFBox_External_Fonts.properties" and build from source. But the better solution would be that you install the usual fonts on your system.

Comment: Thank you so much @TilmanHausherr. I will try both the solution which you suggested and get back.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Still I have a doubt. The font in the generated Image by the above code is same as the PDF except overlapping. Is this due to missing fonts in the system? Because, I just want to solve the overlapping.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I ran the commandline tool in ubuntu 14.10. It generates crystel clear images without any overlapping. You are right. I will try your solution with ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Sorry to waste your time. Ignore my previous comment about Ubuntu 14.10. Because I face the same text overlap issue with 14.10 as well. The only option I have is to try with setting fonts and see how it works.

Comment: @jaghan re "The font in the generated Image by the above code is same as the PDF except overlapping" - I wouldn't assume that, many different sans serif fonts look similar. Please try installing the windows fonts on ubuntu: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2863497/how-to-install-microsoft-fonts-in-linux-office-suites.html

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I already tried installing windows fonts, but the fonts appears to be different from the original. When I ran the command tool on windows machine with the same PDF, it was giving perfect results.

Comment: I'm sorry... this has now reached a point where I can't help, I don't have Ubuntu. You could investigate and try that thing with the two prop files I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I tried adding external fonts using the above properties, but it is not getting loaded. Can you provide me an example to add any one font to those properties. Ex: Time-Roman

Comment: @jaghan Times-Roman=/usr/var/fonts/whatever/Times.ttf However this will work only with TT fonts. I'm not sure if it will work with Type1 fonts (open your PDF with Adobe reader and go to the font dialog in the document properties). There were so many fonts problems in 1.8 that the whole stuff was dumped.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I did that already and I was not able to see any difference. I was able to see the difference when I installed them on my system.

Comment: @jaghan You could present your problem in the user mailingf list (https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/) but mention that you can't use 2.0. Maybe somebody there uses Ubuntu and can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDFBox substitutes font for Helvetica and Times New Roman etc., when it is not found on the server. After installing the above fonts on my Linux machine, the problem got solved.